# AngularJS load in controllers that are in separate files

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/demo', {
                templateUrl : 'assets/pages/home.html'
            })

            // route for the sport page
            .when('/sport', {
                templateUrl : 'assets/pages/sport/home.html',
                controller  : 'sportController'
            });

            // route for the sport page
            .when('/television', {
                templateUrl : 'assets/pages/television/home.html',
                controller  : 'televisionController'
            });
});
```

I have `sportController`in a file called `SportCtrl.js` and `televisionController` in a file called `TvCtrl.js`, how would I be able to load this into my view while using Routing?

Comment: Strange question. Just include those scripts into HTML, Angular will do the rest.

Comment: @dfsq I was trying to keep the html side of it clean and was sure there was a way to load in the js on the fly

Comment: Well you can of course use something like RequireJS.. Or you can include all the scripts and just set up build process with Grunt for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should correctly add your controller in `app` namespace and Angular does all things themselves.

For example, working structure for project:

1. Load Angular, dependencies.
2. Load your application initializer, configs.
3. Load other stuff like controllers, directives, services, filters.

Example of controller code:

```
app.controller('sportController', ['$scope', function($scope){

}])
```

BTW, for Angular file name means nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do a lazy loading of javascript files. This is not an Angular functionality, you have 3 solutions:

- use requireJs to load files on-the-fly.
- include all your javascript files in html
- concatenate all the javascript files in only one file.

I prefer not to use requireJS to prevent one more inclusion and configuration :-)